# Laravel insert into database request()->all() and addition

Tags: laravel

In laravel if i want to insert all the form input and i want to add text in one of the column why cant i use this code?

Example

```
    $B2 = new B2;
    $B2::create([
        request()->all(),
        $B2->column9 = "aaaa",
    ]);
```

The inserted database only insert column9, the other column is Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`create()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Eloquent/Model.php#L557) accepts an array as the only parameter:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
```

You can do this:

```
$data = request()->all();
$data['column9'] = 'aaaa';
B2::create($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

When ever you use request all you must first make sure that you have either fillable fields in your model or guarded = to an empty array so for example:

```
class B2 extends Model
{

protected $table = 'db_table';

protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'name',
];
}
```

or you can use

`protected $guarded = [];`

// PLEASE BE CAREFUL WHEN USING GUARDED AS A POSE TO FILLABLE AS IT OPENS YOU TO SECURITY ISSUES AND SHOULD ONLY REALLY BE USED IN TEST ENVIRONMENTS UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!

As for your create method you should make sure its an associative array like this:

```
$B2::create([
    $B2->column9 => "aaaa",
]);
```

Or you could do something like:

```
    $data = $request->except('_token');
    $B2::create($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to merge the array.

```
$B2::create(array_merge(request()->all(), ['column9' => 'text']));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding to a database in that was it is called mass assignment. Laravel Automatically protects against this so you need to add the firld names to a fillable attribute in your model

```
protected $fillable = ['field1', 'column9'] //etc
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

You also need to make sure you pass an array to the create method

```
$my_array = $request->all()
$my_array['column9'] = 'aaaa';
$B2::create(
    $my_array
);
```